# Using multiple IWizard implementations in ProjectTemplates

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, vsix, project-template, multi-project

I am creating a multi-project solution template for my organization that requires both Nuget packages to be installed and some custom parameters to be set using a Windows Form upon creation. I am deploying it using a VSIX.

I have both these features running separately, but I have not found a way to use both at the same time. According to [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb763141(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb763141%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) Visual Studio should support the use of more than one IWizard in a project template, if I'm understanding it correctly.

I have tried the direct approach and just adding the reference to both wizards in the .vstemplate-file, but only the first is executed. I have also tried to call the Nuget-wizard within my custom Wizard by using the code below, but I guess I have to set the WizardData with the packages-info somehow for this to work...

```
var asm = Assembly.Load("NuGet.VisualStudio.Interop, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a");
var nuget = (IWizard)asm.CreateInstance("NuGet.VisualStudio.TemplateWizard");
nuget.RunStarted(automationObject, replacementsDictionary, runKind, customParams);
```

Can the use of multiple IWizard-implementations be achieved or is this not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no, you cannot register more than one IWizard derived class per template, in the case of nuget, you can callit  by reflection like this:

```
private void AddNugetPackage(VSProject VsProj, string PackageName, string Version)
    {
      try
      {
        Assembly nugetAssembly = Assembly.Load("nuget.core");
        Type packageRepositoryFactoryType = nugetAssembly.GetType("NuGet.PackageRepositoryFactory");
        PropertyInfo piDefault = packageRepositoryFactoryType.GetProperty("Default");
        MethodInfo miCreateRepository = packageRepositoryFactoryType.GetMethod("CreateRepository");
        object repo = miCreateRepository.Invoke(piDefault.GetValue(null, null), new object[] { "https://packages.nuget.org/api/v2" });
        Type packageManagerType = nugetAssembly.GetType("NuGet.PackageManager");
        ConstructorInfo ciPackageManger = packageManagerType.GetConstructor(new Type[] { System.Reflection.Assembly.Load("nuget.core").GetType("NuGet.IPackageRepository"), typeof(string) });
        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(ProjectPath);
        string solPath = di.Parent.FullName;
        string installPath = di.Parent.CreateSubdirectory("packages").FullName;
        object packageManager = ciPackageManger.Invoke(new object[] { repo, installPath });
        MethodInfo miInstallPackage = packageManagerType.GetMethod("InstallPackage",
          new Type[] { typeof(string), System.Reflection.Assembly.Load("nuget.core").GetType("NuGet.SemanticVersion") });
        string packageID = PackageName;
        MethodInfo miParse = nugetAssembly.GetType("NuGet.SemanticVersion").GetMethod("Parse");
        object semanticVersion = miParse.Invoke(null, new object[] { Version });
        miInstallPackage.Invoke(packageManager, new object[] { packageID, semanticVersion });
      }
      catch(Exception ex)
      { 
        // ...
        return;
      }      
    }
```

Comment: this answer was probably true at the time it was answered but as of today using vs 2017 v 15.3.4 I have found that I can in fact add multiple IWizard implementations declared in my .vstemplate file